# Issue creating custom UITableViewCell for a grouped style table

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, cgrectmake

I'm trying to create a custom cell for use in a grouped style `UITableView`. However when I run my code I keep hitting an error at the point marked in my code. I have no idea what is wrong though. Please could someone help me out?

**.h file:**

```
@interface CustomRecommendedStepCell : UITableViewCell
{
    UILabel *stepNumber;
    UITextView *stepInstruction;
}


@property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UILabel *stepNumber;
@property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UITextView *stepInstruction;


@end
```

**.m file:**

```
#import "CustomRecommendedStepCell.h"

@implementation CustomRecommendedStepCell
@synthesize stepNumber, stepInstruction;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    if (self)
    {
        UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        [backgroundView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Slate_bg.png"]];
        self.backgroundView = backgroundView;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        stepNumber = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        stepNumber.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        stepNumber.font = [UIFont fontWithName:kCustomFont1 size:40];
        stepNumber.textColor =[UIColor whiteColor];
        stepNumber.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        stepInstruction = [[UITextView alloc] init];
        stepInstruction.editable = NO;
        stepInstruction.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        stepInstruction.font = [UIFont fontWithName:kCustomFont1 size:23];
        stepInstruction.textColor =[UIColor whiteColor];
        stepInstruction.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        [self.contentView addSubview:stepNumber];
        [self.contentView addSubview:stepInstruction];
    }

    return self;
}


- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    stepNumber.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 50, 60);        // PROBLEM OCCURS HERE!
    stepInstruction.frame = CGRectMake(70, 20, 200, 60);
}


- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

Here is a copy of the log messages I'm receiving:

```
2011-12-22 20:34:09.801 Some App[30945:10703] -[__NSCFString setFrame:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x756b340
2011-12-22 20:34:09.802 Some App[30945:10703] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString setFrame:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x756b340'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x11f052 0x1845d0a 0x120ced 0x85f00 0x85ce2 0xd7c1 0x778322 0x120e72 0x359792d 0x35a1827 0x35a1922 0x771f47 0x924edd 0x7d2fe1 0x7d3589 0x7bedfd 0x7cd851 0x778301 0x120e72 0x359792d 0x35a1827 0x3527fa7 0x3529ea6 0x3529580 0xf39ce 0x8a670 0x564f6 0x55db4 0x55ccb 0x3ab4879 0x3ab493e 0x739a9b 0x2128 0x2085 0x1)
terminate called throwing an exception
```

Comment: your object looks like a `NSString`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method you seem to do something like

```
cell.stepNumber = @"text";
```

instead of

```
cell.stepNumber.text = @"text";
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the problem is in this code.. check your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method as Eugene suggested. I think you might be returning a `NSString` instead of a `UITableViewCell`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like by the time `layoutSubviews` is called, your `stepNumber` label has already been released (or never allocated).

My guess would be that you need to look at the way you are instantiating your custom cell. Are you positive your initWithStyle: method is getting called?

Can you post your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method of your view controller?

Comment: The log mentions that `NSCFString` doesn't recognize the `setFrame:` selector.

Comment: That doesn't mean anything, the ivar could be just pointing to garbage memory previously used by NSCFString...